# RegEx to allow numbers and only one dot - E.g. it should not allow 1.1

Tags: regex, ng-pattern

I want my hours input field to allow only numbers utill `2nd` decimal point (numbers with only a single dot).

I used this expression for the same `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/` and this allows `1.1.` which should not be allowed

Comment: Could you please share a demo fiddle? Did you use `type="text"`? The [test page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) says the pattern works well.

Comment: This site may help you evaluate your regex: https://regex101.com

Comment: I used type="number"

Comment: @ronakbarbhaya: You need to set it to "text".

Comment: Does it work? Please share the full relevant code.

Comment: Yup it worked thanks, but if i want this to be worked with type="number" then what should be done?

Comment: It won't work at all then, it is not possible.

Comment: i have added lower and upper limit as 1 and 60 respectively for this, so if i include type="text" then it doesn't give me the validations for this limit.. so could you find another solution for this

Comment: There is no other solution if you plan to use a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is matching the right type of input. The type of the input should be set to text:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" />
```

A regex validation check is not supported with `type="number"`.

**UPDATE**

To only allow float/integer values between 1 and 60, use

```
/^([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60(\.0{1,2})?$)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vO6cX6/1)

- `^` - start of sting
- `([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60(\.0{1,2})?$)` - one of the following:

  - `[1-9]` - digit from `1` to `9` (no `0` allowed)
  - `[1-5][0-9]` - numbers from 10 to 59
  - `60(\.0{1,2})?$` - 60 that is  optionally followed with `.0` or `.00` and then an end of string should follow
- `(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` - optional (1 or 0) `.` followed with 1 or 2 any digits before...
- `$` - the end of string

Comment: then how can i apply upper and lower limit as 60 and 1 for this field?

Comment: I.e. from 1 till 60?

Comment: For 1 to 60, use [`/^([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60(\.0{1,2})?$)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/vO6cX6/1)